# Keeping paragraph tops lined up with variable headers

Tags: css

I have three article excerpts displayed on my home page displayed inside variable-width divs. Each article has a header followed by a short paragraph. Ideally all of the paragraph tops would line up, however some article titles are long enough to wrap to a second line, while others aren't. This results in the paragraphs starting at different points. See below:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4q70x1kL/1/)

```
<style>
#row { width: 200px; }
.box { float: left; width: 100px; padding: 5px; }
</style>

<div id="row">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>
      This text sits just below the title.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>Title that's a lot longer and so gets a second line.</h3>
    <p>
      This text sits just below the title, but since the title is twice as tall, it sits below the text in the first box.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can create the effect that I want, seen in the JSFiddle link above, by just having a row of headers followed by a row of paragraphs. However the design I've been given doesn't display them in neat cell-like ways like that. They have stuff between them, next to them etc. which makes that a bit problematic.

I was wondering if there was an easier way to have the paragraphs match their starting point, that could also handle a screen resize causing a single-line header to wrap around into a two-line one.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this look using the tabular layout properties.

```css
.box {
  display: table-cell;
}
.box h3 {
  display: table-caption;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="row1">
  <div class="box">
    <h3>This is a title</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque dolor vel lorem mollis pellentesque. Nullam consequat bibendum tellus et ullamcorper. Etiam quis suscipit tortor. Pellentesque quis magna id mauris euismod convallis vitae
      eget ligula. Vivamus accumsan sem quis sem accumsan, sed eleifend tellus gravida.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>This is a longer title</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque dolor vel lorem mollis pellentesque. Nullam consequat bibendum tellus et ullamcorper. Etiam quis suscipit tortor. Pellentesque quis magna id mauris euismod convallis vitae
      eget ligula. Vivamus accumsan sem quis sem accumsan, sed eleifend tellus gravida.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <h3>This is a longer title still. Look at it go!</h3>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris scelerisque dolor vel lorem mollis pellentesque. Nullam consequat bibendum tellus et ullamcorper. Etiam quis suscipit tortor. Pellentesque quis magna id mauris euismod convallis vitae
      eget ligula. Vivamus accumsan sem quis sem accumsan, sed eleifend tellus gravida.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```